# Video capture in HTML 5

Tags: html, tags, html5-video, html5-canvas

How to capture video from  a video device and make that video available in HTML5 canvas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you should use [HTML5 Video Capturing feature](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).

This way instead of installing any plugins tell users to upgrade their browser ;)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the HTML5 standard doesn't offer microphone and camera capabilities.
But, there's a [jQuery plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) that offers just that using a small flash utility