# Is it possible to grab the content of the HTML 5 Canvas element to a video programatically?

Tags: java, gwt, video, html5-canvas

1. What I'm looking for is any API/library which helps to capture the HTML 5 animation running in the canvas element and convert it into a video?
2. Also the audio too should be captured in the output video.

OR

Alternative approach:
Say I have a GWT (Java code) which does some mathematical calculations and renders animation onto a [CanvasElement](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/dom/client/CanvasElement.html). Is it possible to render a video instead of outputting the animation to the CanvasElement? Again the audio should be captured as well.

HTML 5 Video example:
http://www.craftymind.com/factory/html5video/CanvasVideo.html

Comment: Hello.. Nobody out there with any answer/hints/pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how some programs sample youtube videos. Also, have a look at this answer: [Video capture in HTML 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386675/video-capture-in-html-5)